# How to establish group correspondence

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $A$ and $B$ be groups. Let $G =A \times B$. Let $H = \{(a, e)|a \in A\}$. $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Show that the left cosets of $H$ in $G$ are in one-to-one correspondence with $B$.

I am not sure how to approach this question. My current thought is $g_1$ has the form of $(a_1,b_1)$ and $g_1 H = (a_1*a,b_1)$. I also know $a_1*a \in A$. However, I don't know how to prove one-to-one correspondence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two left cosets $(a,b)H$ and $(c,d)H$. When will they be equal? If
\begin{align*}
(a,b)H & = (c,d)H\\
(a,b)(c,d)^{-1}H &=H\\
(ac^{-1}, bd^{-1})H & =H.
\end{align*}
So we want $(ac^{-1}, bd^{-1}) \in H$. For that $ac^{-1} \in A$ (which it will because $A$ is a group) and we also want $bd^{-1}=e$. This means $b=d$. So what do we get out of this?

If we have $(a,\color{red}{b}) \in A \times B$ and $(c,\color{red}{b}) \in A \times B$, then they belong to the same left coset of $H$. Said differently, for each $b \in B$, there is a unique left coset $(a,\color{red}{b})H$.

---

In terms of functions, we can have $f:B \longrightarrow G/H$ be defined as 
$$f(b)=(e_a,b)H, \quad \text{where }\quad e_a \text{ is the identity of } A.$$
Now use the line of argument I have stated above to conclude bijectivity

Comment: Thanks so much! I have one more question. For (ac^-1,bd^-1)H=H, if it is an equality, shouldn't it be eH = H? Why you instead write (ac^−1,bd^−1) ∈ H？

Comment: @davidD If we have $gH=H$, then this implies $g \in H$.

Comment: @davidD you have asked quite a few questions but haven't accepted any answers. Any reasons?